# GAE tasks that runs for one hour?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task

When configuring my tasks following the guide of Google App Engine, I read that it was possible to have some [tasks runs for more than 10 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push#task_deadlines) (the default limit) and go to one hour, by using a manual or basic scaling module.

I tried to configure it this way (with the following yaml configurations) but my tasks are always killed after 10 minutes, not 1 hour.

What I am doing wrong?

queue.yaml :

```
queue:
 - name: long_process
   max_concurrent_requests: 10
   rate: 1/s

... (other tasks)
```

long_process_queue_module.yaml:

```
module: long-process-queue-module
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
version: 1
threadsafe: true

instance_class: B1
manual_scaling:
  instances: 5

handlers:
- url: /_ah/queue/myhandler
  script: wsgi.application
  login: admin
```

What is wrong ? How can I set the duration to 1 hour?

In case it's important, I'd also like to be able to run this tasks more than one at once. I currently set `instances: 5` suspecting it would run 5 long-process concurrently, but maybe I'm wrong here too?

Comment: There is no limit on how long a task can run in basic or manual scaling instance. It can run for days, if necessary. An instance can shut down, but if it stays up, it can keep running your task indefinitely.

Comment: Is this true? I know background thread has max lifetime of 24h, not sure about task though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the task to be run in the `long-process-queue-module`, you can specify the target field in the queue.yaml, or when you enqueue a task. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#target
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#task_target

Comment: Can you tell me how GAE will handle multiple concurrent process ? Is there a rule to say "run only X process at the same time, and queue the other for later" ? Is it `max_concurrent_requests` ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah you can control that from the `max_concurrent_requests ` in the queue param. There is another `max_concurrent_requests` in the app.yaml to control threads per instance basis.

Comment: I implemented your answer and that did the trick. I accepted your answer. Thanks